# Run time of pseudo code in big theta notation

Tags: runtime-analysis, landau-notation, pseudocode

I am looking for the run time of the following pseudo code.

```
FunctionA(n)
a ← 2
b ← 2n²
while b>1
    a ← a +1 
    c ← n
    while c ≥ n
        b ← b - a
        a ← a/2
        c ← 2n/c
```

So I think the inner while loop has a run time complexity which will be definde by the outer loop since c is allways 2 and because it allways executes as long as the outer loop runs. 
The outer loop decreases b with every step by 1 and a. a is allways the half of the precursor. Therefor I have the feeling that the outer loop runs $\Theta(log_2(n))$ and hence the result is $\Theta(2*log_2(n))$.
Would somebody comfirm this?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: If n = 1 the program runs forever. Your analysis seems way off. I'd say O (n^2). Not a clue where you got a log from.

Comment: Analyse the inner loop for the cases n = 1, n = 2, and n ≥ 3.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it's an Infinite loop for n = 1 and n = 2 but why is it $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$?